# Recommended way to distribute my python package without uploading on PyPi

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-10

I am trying to install a local package from source with pip, but my code does not get copied in the site-packages folder. Instead a folder is created with a json file linking to the path of my python source code.
Is this expected behaviour ? what is the difference with the difference with installation in developement mode (with the -e flag).

My working path looks like this:

```
├── setup.py
└── my_package
    ├── __init__.py
    └── module.py
```

My setup.py file looks like this:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(name='my_package', version='0.0.1')
```

I am typing:

```
python -m pip install .
```

and then when I import my package in python, it tells me the imported package is located in my source code folder:

```
>>> import my_package
>>> my_package.__file__
path/to/my/desktop
```

What would be the recommended way to distribute my package to my collegues, without uploading it on PyPi ?
Also can someone please explain to me the differences between .wheel, .tar.gz, and .egg files that can be generated with setuptools, and their use case ?

Comment: Did you check this link: https://packaging.python.org/ There are a lot of resources on the topic packaging.

Comment: Related to the question "What would be the recommended way to distribute my package to my collegues": You can tell pip to install from various sources. Which source might depends on what you and your collegues plan todo. If they shall contribute I would recommend to let pip install from a CVS, e.g. from a git repo where this package `my_package` is located. Search for: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pip+install+from+git+repository

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had already read the python packaging guide.
The guide mentions that you can [install from source tree](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-a-local-src-tree), however in both normal mode and developement mode (the -e flag) the package is not copied in the site package with my version of python (3.8).
My objective is mostly to distribute my package for other collegues to use it. I am the only maintainer of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that suits me.
I generate a .whl file from my package using the command

```
python -m pip wheel .
```

In the folder containing the setup.py.
This generates a .whl file, that my collegues can install using the command

```
python -m pip install .\my_package-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

ziping you source code (including the setup.py) would work too, but it looks less clean.

Also i found out why installing from source without the -e flag was not copying my code in my "site-package" folder. Installing a package generates two folder: A "my_package-0.0.1.dist-info" folder and "my_module" folder.
I was missing the "package" kwarg in my setup.py script, so the version info folder was created but not the folder containing the code. Here below a corrected setup.py

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(name="my_package", version='0.0.1', packages=["my_package"])
```